# how to properly allocate partition space

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, vaio

I want to dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7 on a Sony Vaio notebook. When the option comes up to drag the divider left or right for setting the partition size, it does not specify which would be the ideal partitioning. I'm new to Ubuntu, and really like it. My question is which way should I move the divider, and how much memory to allocate to each side? Thanks for any help you could offer.

Comment: As per MY experience, the left side partition is for the OS that is newly installed. I had installed 12.10 alongside the existent 12.04 and found that the memory reading on the right of the slider was for 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid some boot problems, I generally recommend:

1. via the Windows tools, shrink your Windows partition to 80GB.
2. install Ubuntu in the remaining space.
3. if any boot problem, via the Gparted tool, reduce the Ubuntu partition to 20GB. The remaining space can be used to store documents.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace for more info.